# Linux distro for NAS Server for Home

Tags: webserver, nas, home-server

I am wondering as is there dedicated servers for routing as (ipcop,pfsnese) and also for telephony as (elastix, asteriskNow) and other similar projects , Does exists something for home made NAS servers. I want to use some of old hardware to make my home server for holding videos,pictures and others media. Is there any rabbit in hat for that or Ill must go from begin collecting all pulses together to make NAS server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[OpenFiler](http://www.openfiler.com/) and [FreeNAS](http://freenas.org/FreeNAS) are the two that spring to mind.

If you want more info on making a decision, [these questions might help](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/freenas+openfiler).

Answer (score 5):

http://www.openfiler.com/community or FreeBSD based http://freenas.org/FreeNAS

Answer (score 1):

You can use your Ubuntu box for NAS too:
http://tjworld.net/wiki/Linux/Ubuntu/HardyRAID5EncryptedLVM